# Using URL Name in Articles

Tags: visualforce, knowledge, articles

i created an article in salesforce.its url name is How-do-I-Change-my-Password .i have visualforce page.in which there is a link when clicked should redirect to article.i put href attribute value as href="/How-do-I-Change-my-Password" .Please but its giving me "URL No Longer Exist." Please guidleine how to use Article URL Name field in salesforce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url should be

> href="/articles/articletype/article-urlname"

So for your case find the article type and append articles/articletype followed by / and article URL